# Composing a workflow using IoC

Tags: dependency-injection, workflow, inversion-of-control, mef, workflow-foundation

I am building a WPF application that uses an IoC container for dependency injection (MEF in my case).  The application contains several detailed processes that we are modeling as WF workflows.  However, some (not all) of the activities rely on services and other components that are managed by the IoC container.  I see a few possible ways to accomplish this but none of them seem to follow best-practices.  They are:

1. Use a service-locator in the constructor or Execute method of each activity to locate
   and set the dependencies. Personally, I don't like service locators as I believe they violate one of the tenants of DI where code doesn't know where or how the dependency is created. It also makes the activities less testable (or at least adds a couple of steps to the testing process). I've seen some examples on StackOverflow and CodePlex that use a WF Services extension that basically works the same way.  I'm not using WF Services, so that isn't an option.
2. Export each of the activities and have the workflow import them.
   This would ensure that the container has satisfied all of the
   dependencies before we need them but means we aren't building the
   workflow in XAML.
3. Export the workflow and have it import the dependencies needed by
   the activities. Then I would have to set the dependencies as
   parameters for the activities to consume. Not only will this result
   in a lot of overhead code in the workflow, but it now means that the
   workflow requires knowledge of the dependencies for all of the
   activities. If an activity changes, is added or removed, I now have
   to make changes to the workflow to accomodate any changes to the
   dependencies.
4. Take the same approach as #3 except instead of exporting the
   workflow, have a controlling class that is exported, imports all of
   the dependencies and sets them as input parameters for the workflow
   itself. Each activity would pull the dependencies it needs.  This
   has all of the same problems as #3 with more code to maintain.

**So, my question is, what approach should I take?** (I.e. what approach have you taken?)

I am also assuming the above list is not comprehensive and hope someone will suggest a better option, if one exists.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Approach two seems to be most adequate. You might use some activity declaration in xaml which will be used later to import real one.

EDIT:

```
<wf:Workflow.Activities></activities:PassThrough UserId="mstewart"></wf:Workflow.Activities>
```

and then you could have something among those lines

```
interface IActivityInfo
{
  IActivity ImportActivity();
}
interface IActivity<TActivityInfo> where TActivityInfo : IActivityInfo
{
  IActivityInfo Info { get; }
}

class PassThrough : IActivityInfo
{   
  public IActivity ImportActivity(){ return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IActivity<PassThrough>>(); }
}

[Export(typeof(IActivity<PassThrough>))]
class PassThroughActivity : IActivity<PassThrough>
{
}
```

This approach would let you easily separate xaml design process from underlying activity.

Comment: Please elaborate on your second sentence.

Comment: So ultimately you are going back to using the service locator pattern to resolve the activity.  In your case, if I'm understanding, you've just created a wrapper that can be plugged into the XAML to abstract the locator. What you don't show is that both PassThrough and PassThroughActivity have to subclass Activity (or another Activity sub-type) and PassThrough will have to implement all of the methods and delegate to the "imported" PassThroughActivity.  That's a lot of code to maintain, especially when there will be dozens of custom activities that will need this behavior in the solution.

Comment: ActivityInfo needs only to hold information needed to properly initialize Activity instance.

Comment: In this example I am not using Locator xaml abstraction... ActivityInfo is not an Activity, (it is builder pattern kind of). It only needs to hold enough information to be able to properly initialize Activity instance. ServiceLocator is used to resolve dependency(it is not really dependency at this time... ) during the method call, not during ActivityInfo initialization in xaml which may happen much earlier. So... in xaml I got ActivityInfo. When it is time to generate real workflow out of it I call an Import. Yeah... I have experienced this sort of troubles at my work.

Comment: I'm curious if you've actually implemented this or if it's just theoretical?  I still fail to see how PassThrough is not a subclass of Activity.  In order for the code to run as part of the workflow, it must comply with the contract expected by the workflow runtime (Activity).  For instance, who calls ImportActivity and when is it called?  WF expects to call Execute(...) when an activity is to run, where is Execute in your model if PassThrough does not subclass Activity?

Comment: I'm not even sure I follow your original XAML as it doesn't resemble anything I recall coming across working with WF.  What version are you referencing?

Comment: Custom workflows... not a WWF. If you are working with Prism you should know about ModuleInfo. The code I showed works quite the same.

Comment: I'm working with WF and MEF - not Prism nor a custom workflow engine.

Comment: Once can live without the other :)

Comment: Anyway... having it implemented the way I see it, is possible and not hard with WWF. First of all check out the builder pattern.http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBuilder.aspx#_self1 That might help you understand the logic behind design and final objects separation. If you'll not get it by that time it would be hard for me to explain it more without writing code for yourself. :)

Comment: We can agree to disagree if necessary, but my question is specifically related to WF which does matter because of the prescriptive nature of the runtime (activities have to be, well, Activities).  As for the rest, as an architect I have no questions about the patterns you are following nor the logic behind your code - only the fact that it is incomplete given the scope of the question.